# How to run installed python script?

Tags: python, windows, packaging, distutils

I used distutils to install my python package, with this setup.py :

```
import distutils.core

args = {
    'name' :            'plugh',
    'version' :         '1.0',
    'scripts' :         [ "scripts/plugh" ],
    'packages':         [ "plugh" ],
}

d = distutils.core.setup(
    **args
)
```

On linux/mac, it works as expected:

```
% plugh
hello world
%
```

On windows, the script "plugh" does not run:

```
C:\Python25\Scripts>plugh
'plugh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python25\Scripts>
```

I found the bug report at http://bugs.python.org/issue7231 that the \Scripts directory is not added to PATH when you install python, so I applied the workaround described in that ticket (i.e. add C:\Python25\Scripts to PATH)

```
C:\Python25\Scripts>path
PATH=c:\Python25\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Legato\nsr\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\
WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\python2
5;c:\local;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Is this something that just doesn't work on Windows?  And if so, how exactly are you supposed to use python scripts on a windows machine?

I suppose that I could detect Windows, and add an additional script to the list, called "plugh.bat" containing something like:

```
@echo off
c:\python25\python.exec c:\python25\scripts\plugh %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

but is that really the right answer here?  I would have thought that with all the customizations that distutils contains for windows, there would be a better answer than that.

Comment: BTW, the parameters sequence %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 could be replaced with %* if you just need to pass all batch input to pyhton script (or any other executable).

Answer (score 6):

windows uses the extension of the file to determine how it will run.

Name your file `plugh.py` and use `plugh.py` on the prompt to call it.

Comment: In case you want the user to click on the `.py` file, you can associate `.py` files with pythonw.exe instead of python.exe so that the terminal does not stay open: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Answer (score 5):

1. If you use [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/), it will already add the `C:\PythonXY\Scripts` directory to your `%PATH%` (ActivePython 2.6 additionally adds [PEP 370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)'s `%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts` to `%PATH%`) during the installation.
2. For deploying scripts on Windows machine, better use **Distribute** which will take care of installing .exe wrappers for your scripts *and* invoking the actual Python with which your package was installed (to avoid conflict with multiple Python installations -- so naming your script to end .py is just not enough). For more on this topic, read about [**entry points**](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in Distribute documentation.