# Trouble running scripts installed by virtualenv-commands on Windows

Tags: python, windows, exec, virtualenv, virtualenv-commands

There's a problem with running installed scripts on Windows which can be seen below

```
C:\Users\Piotr>where python
C:\program files\Python\2.7\python.exe
C:\Users\Piotr>python c:\program files\Python\2.7\scripts\ve init
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Is "ve-init" executable in the current path?
C:\Users\Piotr>
```

I tried to resolve this by following advices in [How to run installed python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829524/) question but with no luck:

```
C:\Users\Piotr>assoc .py
.py=Python.File
C:\Users\Piotr>ftype Python.File
Python.File=c:\program files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*
C:\Users\Piotr>dir /b "c:\program files\python\2.7\scripts"
easy_install-2.7-script.py
easy_install-2.7.exe
easy_install-script.py
easy_install.exe
pip-2.7-script.py
pip-2.7.exe
pip-script.py
pip.exe
ve-clone
ve-extend
ve-init.py
ve.py
virtualenv-script.py
virtualenv.exe    
C:\Users\Piotr>python c:\program files\Python\2.7\Scripts\ve.py init
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Is "ve-init" executable in the current path?
```

I think what's special in this case is that `ve` script runs command scripts (`ve-init`, `ve-clone` etc.) through OS (`os.execvp()`).

Comment: I read the post you linked to. It doesn't look to me like you followed its instructions? You need `ve-init` to be runnable by windows. How does windows know how to run it if it's not `ve-init.py` with the correct file association?

Comment: I followed these instructions but didn't want to make my question too long so I skipped results. Now I added them to my question.

Comment: It still looks to me like you're trying to run `ve-init` when you need to be running `ve-init.py` -- there is no `ve-init` in that list. Even with the association you still need the full file name?

Comment: Right, that's what `ve` script does (`command = 've-%s' % command` and then `return os.execvp(command, (command, ) + args)`. I would have to modify these scripts and I'd like to avoid doing this if there's some other way to get it working.

Comment: There isn't any way to do this on windows, unless you're using bash in MSYS or something that can interpret the hashbang at the beginning of the file. Otherwise you need the files to have the `.py` extension or call `python` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `.py` extension to `PATHEXT` environment variable so that Python scripts could be run without specifying extension (as long as they are on the `PATH`).

Nevertheless this is not enough to get *virtualenv-commands* working on Windows because this package uses Unix specific tools which are not available on Windows.

Funny, I guess the idea behind creating *virtualenv-commands* was to make it more portable than *virtualenvwrapper* by not using shell scripts but it seems current implementation supports only Unix.